# A Prolog predicate result

Tags: prolog

I have written a Prolog relation `remove(E,L,R)` that is true if `R` is the list which results from removing one instance of `E` from list `L`. The relation is false if `E` isn't a member of `L`.

I want to know the result of the following query

```
remove(p(X),[a,p(a),p(p(a)),p(p(p(a)))],R).
```

Comment: What on earth are you having trouble with?

Comment: post your implementation, depending on how you have coped with the variable unification you might be able to match and remove only the first element which the pattern unifies to.

Comment: equivalence `remove(A,B,C):-select(A,B,C).` ?

Answer (score 1):

So? Just ask. Not us, but ask Prolog. The result *should* be

```
?- remove(p(X),[a,p(a),p(p(a)),p(p(p(a)))],R).
X = a,
R = [a, p(p(a)), p(p(p(a)))]
```

or something along those lines, if you've written it right. If you allow backtracking (in other words, removing *an* element from your list, starting with the first), you'll get something like

```
?- remove(p(X),[a,p(a),p(p(a)),p(p(p(a)))],R).
X = a,
R = [a, p(p(a)), p(p(p(a)))] ;
X = p(a),
R = [a, p(a), p(p(p(a)))] ;
X = p(p(a)),
R = [a, p(a), p(p(a))] ;
false.
```